# Exterior Door - Jam Placement

Tags: drywall, doors, framing, stucco, jamb

I'm installing a pre-hung exterior door on the back of the garage. The door jam is 4 9/16" wide. The total width of the wall (interior face to exterior face) is about 5 3/4"

The door jam is about 1 - 1 1/8" too narrow.

My question is where should I place the face of the door jam? Should I place it flush with the inside face of the drywall or place it flush with the exterior of what will be the face of the finished stucco?

Currently, it's just studs and sheathing. I'm looking for a best practice since I have options right now.

**Wall Assembly**

```
Moving from the Interior to Exterior
Drywall 5/8"
Wall framing 3 1/2"
OSB Sheathing 1/2"
Stucco about 1 1/8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the exterior edge of the jamb flush with the stucco. This will make it easier to seal against water. Not sure if exterior trim will be used, but it will offer more protection against the elements.

On the inside edge you'll need to rip a fill piece to make up the 1 inch shy door jamb. Glue and finish nail it to the (2) sides and the top of the door jamb.

Comment: I had to do a similar trim job on an interior door (old skool, true 2x4 wall, reframed with new skool nominal "2x4"). After extending the jambs, I resawed some lumber to make a veneer to cover the joint in the jamb. Of course, this was on my bedroom door and I wanted it to look nice. OPs exterior door may not warrant the extra effort.

Comment: Thank you, I like your solution and reason. I will bring the edge of the jamb to the exterior sheathing plus 1 1/8" .This will do as you said, allow me to have a great tight seal to place some basic brick molding to. I'll be able to rip a jam extension to the inside and trim it out adequate for a garage interior. Thanks for the simple advice.

Answer (score 1):

Will the top of the door get any rain or snow? If so, do you plan to add any flashing at the top? (I hope so) There should be a top flashing that goes under the stucco and turns out over the trim of the door. Also, typically the door is set to the sheathing and the stucco is placed around the door. If you could get the door set to the sheathing, then the flashing would work, and so would the jamb.

Comment: Great point. This door is in southern California, tucked under an eve on the predominant leeward wind side of the home. This door will not get a top flashing, but the point is well taken.